# jquery - datepicker - is there a way to make the calendar dyanimically show availibility and seasons

Tags: jquery, dynamic, asp-classic, datepicker

I am making a booking system for a hotel I work for. The previous system used flash and I have availabilities established in a db and the different dates correspond to different seasons, and therefore different prices. It would be kind of important to allow the user to see this info when they use the datepicker. Can I make datepicker appear showing such availaibility and seasons? Imagine a calendar where days are in 5 different colors, reflecting different prices, and some dates have a padlock implying that they cannot be chosen. I can believe this to be close to impossible with datepicker calendar, unless there is funciotnality already sewn in. In that case, is there another solution that springs to mind?

I would like to keep my question quite general, like I have, but people will probably ask me what I'm programming in. Many aren't going to like this, but I have all the dates and daily calendar values programmes into a db and the site is in ASP classic, and has been using a flash front end I made from scratch a long time ago, that works and is lovely and highly dynamic, all info updates immediately and is contained in one area, visible in a single glance, but flash is now a limitation I must avoid and I have to change it. The site is still ASP (so vbscript). I can do it in python if required, but php is not in my knowledge bank, and ASP .net neither. The java in datepickr is quite intense and I wouldn't know how to rip it to shreds to make it dynamic. Be gentle. I am a "highly experienced beginner" from the old days, and have never had to ask a question on stackoverflow until now (although  ihave found a million answers over the years).

Comment: depends on which datepicker plugin you are looking at, I don't see why this would be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed such a thing in a booking portal I've developed. The `beforeShowDay` option allows you to do what you want! In my case I wanted to disable unavailable dates according to the availability I get from the server. following is the code I've written.

```
beforeShowDay:function(crrDate){
    var dateBlocks = $('#room-blocks').val();
    var currentDateString = $.datepicker.formatDate(DATE_FORMAT, crrDate);
    return [dateBlocks.indexOf(currentDateString) == -1];
},
```

The `$('#room-blocks').val()` contains an array with all the availability data! 
You would get an idea on the concept if you read the `datepicker` api. You can modify the above code to change on different types of data according to your need.